# Is there a faster way to match and multiply Dataframe values based on index values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, match

I have two data frames:
one (multiindex) of size (1113, 7897) containing values for different country and sectors in columns and different IDs in the row, example:

**F_Frame:**

```
     AT              BE            ...
     Food   Energy   Food   Energy ...
ID1  
ID2
...
```

In another dataframe (**CC_LO**) I have factor-values with corresponding country and IDs that I would like to match with the former dataframe (**F_frame**), so that I multiply values in F_frame with factorvalues on CC_LO if they match by country and ID. If they do not match, I put a zero.

The code I have so far, seems to work, but it runs very slowly. Is there a smarter way to match the tables based on the index/header names?
(The code loops over 49 countries and multiply by the same factor for every 163 sector within the country)

```
LO_impacts = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((1113,7987)))

for i in range(0, len(F_frame)): 
    for j in range(0, 49): 
        for k in range(0, len(CF_LO)): 
            if (F_frame.index.get_level_values(1)[i] == CF_LO.iloc[k,1] and 
                F_frame.columns.get_level_values(0)[j*163] == CF_LO.iloc[k,2]): 
                LO_impacts.iloc[i,(j*163):((j+1)*163)] = F_frame.iloc[i,(j*163):((j+1)*163)] * CF_LO.iloc[k,4] 
            else:
                LO_impacts.iloc[i,(j*163):((j+1)*163)] == 0
```

Comment: Let's look at inner join using merge and pandas does automatically perform most operations using indexes (both the row index and column headers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have made two dataframes, then i setted a new index for the second dataFrame as below:

[image: Image1!]

then i have used the function assign() to create a new column for df2:

`df2=df2.assign(gre_multiply=lambda x: x.gre*df1.gre)`

> don't forget to make df2=, i forgot it in the picture.

and i have got the following dataFrame:

[image: Image2!]

of course it look at index you can check using a calculator, it returns values as float, it is easy now to convert to int later `df2.gre_multiply.astype(int)`
but before that you need to fillna because if the indexes of the two dataframes don't match it will return Nan

```
df2.gre_multiply=df2.gre_multiply.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

# Creating dummy data
data = pd.DataFrame([
[2.0, 1.1, 6.7, 4.5],
[4.3, 5.7, 8.6, 9.0],
[5.5, 6.8, 9.0, 4.7],
[5.5, 6.8, 9.0, 4.7],
], index = ["S1", "S1", "S2", "S2"], columns = mindex)

mindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["AT", "DK"], ["Food", "Energy"]])

mul_factor = pd.DataFrame({"Country": ['AT', 'DK', 'AT', 'DK'],
          "Value": [1.0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.6],
         }, index = ['S1', 'S1', 'S2', 'S2'])


new_data = data.copy()
new_data.columns = data.columns.to_frame()[0].to_list()

# Reshaping the second Dataframe
mat = mul_factor.reset_index().pivot(index = 'Country', columns='index')
mat.index.name = None
mat = mat.T.reset_index(0, drop = True)
mat.index.name = None

new_data.multiply(mat) # Required result
```

Please let me know if I've misunderstood your question. You might have to modify the code a bit to accommodate missing country values.

Comment: Thanks! This seems like a good approach, just what I was looking for. Is it possible to keep the multiindex levels, when multiplying, or does it have to be between two single index dataframes?

Comment: As far as I know, it works nicely only for single index dataframes